# Unsteady RPM when ac is on

Tags: rough-idle, rpm

Hi guys I have a 2019 Lexus GX460 with a mileage around 8000. Recently I noticed that whenever I turn the ac on in idle, the rpm went up and down every few seconds with loud noises from the engine bay, but it went back to normal as long as I turn off the ac. Can someone please tell me is it normal or something is wrong. I have heard some people said that it normally won’t happen to car with large displacement engine tho.

Comment: those people saying that are incorrect. The load from AC will impact any engine. You may have issues with your compressor, though, if you are getting odd noises - what kind are you hearing.

Comment: It sounds similar to when I step on the gas, and I can feel the car is shaking when it sounds.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you believe there is an issue with your vehicle, take it to the Lexus service department and have them take a look at it. I realize they are more than likely going to say, "Oh, there's nothing wrong", however, there's a reason TMC gives you a warranty ... to cover such things. This is a No Cost option to you, other than your time.